# Space X is connected IFF no continuous surjection exists

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

> Question:
>
> A space X is connected IFF there exists no continuous surjective function
>
> $f:X\rightarrow S^{0}$

where $S^{0}=\left \{ x \in \mathbb{R}:\left \| x \right \| =r\right \}$

Suppose X is a connected space.
There exists no separation of X and hence exists no pair U,V of disjoint non-empty open subsets of X whose union is X.
Also, this implies that the only subsets of X that are both open and closed in X are the empty sets and X itself.

Can anyone take me further?

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you really want $r$ in the definition of $S^0$, or is that supposed to be $1$?

Comment: The question did not specify. I 'used' "r" by the definition by by wikipedia. 
Can we assume r=1?

Comment: Yes: the standard definition of $S^n$ for any $n$ is $\{x\in\Bbb R^{n+1}:\|x\|=1\}$. And as a hint for the question: given that $r=1$, exactly what does the set $S^0$ look like?

Comment: It looks like a circle of radius 1?

Comment: It can’t: you can’t fit a circle into $\Bbb R$, the real line. What real numbers $x$ have $\|x\|=1$?

Comment: a line of length 1?

Comment: I’m afraid not. Perhaps you’re not realizing that $\|x\|$ is the same as $|x|$: the norm in $\Bbb R$ is just the absolute value. What real numbers have absolute value $1$/

Comment: Just the elements -1,+1@BrianM.Scott

Comment: There you go. And if $f:X\to S^0$ is a continuous surjection, the sets $f^{-1}[\{-1\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ are disjoint, non-empty, and ... what?

Comment: ...and are open sets due to the assumed continuity of f.@BrianM.Scott

Comment: Right, because $\{-1\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open subsets of $S^0$. And that means that $X$ isn’t connected.

Comment: So in effect, we're using contrapositivity to prove the theorem? It seems like a common strategy in the concept of "connectedness".
@BrianM.Scott

Comment: It’s pretty common generally. The trick is to learn to recognize in any given case which is likely to be easier to prove, an implication or its contrapositive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline**:

- Prove the contrapositives instead, since negations are tricky.
- Note that $S^0$ is just the discrete topology on a set with two elements, which is of course disconnected.
- If such a continuous surjection exists, then we can produce a similar separation on $X$ by taking preimages of the separation on $S^0$.
- If such a separation on $X$ exists, then we can produce a continuous surjection by mapping each nontrivial clopen set to each of the two elements in $S^0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $S^0$ (taking $r = 1$, but any $r > 0$ yields the same essential space) is just $\{-1,1\}$ in the discrete topology.

If a surjection $f$ exists, what sets are $f^{-1}[\{-1\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$? This should also suggest the other direction.

Comment: For your effort, I'll like to say "Thank you"